# Is there any function that can count with char value?

Tags: java, string, char, counter, frequency

Write a program to accept a sentence and perform the following tasks:

1. **Count number of vowels  and consonants present in each word**
2. Generate the output of the frequency in form of a bar graph, where **V denotes vowels and C denotes consonants** as shown below:

Example:

**INPUT:-**

HOW ARE YOU?

**OUTPUT:-**

WORD COUNT:

HOW
**V**

**CC**

ARE
**VV**

**C**

YOU
**VV**

**C**

The thing I am asking is that how can I print  V and C, the number of times the vowels and consonants is occurring.. because I can perform this with digits(like if 2 vowel are there so print 2) but I can't figure that out with char value(here, V and C)

I tried this with for loop with if statement.. but that ain't working

Please help me with this... **exams are round the corner**

Comment: Please, take some time to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What do have tried so far? Code, input...

Comment: I find your question confusing.  Please post the solution  you tried.  And before posting again, please take the [tour].

Comment: _I tried this with if loop_ there is not a thing like an "if loop" - an if statement does not loop. There are "for" loops and "while" loops and "do ... while" loops and IMHO any of these three loops should work.

Comment: I am sorry Mr. Thomas, thank you for correcting me

Comment: We can help you a lot better if you post what you have tried so far. Otherwise we are just coding it for you and not actually helping you.

Comment: Sure, Mr. Matthew but it has error

Comment: My code:- 
import java.util.Scanner;

public class sen
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
(

Scanner sc new Scanner(System.in);

String sen "". wd":

char ch

int i, slen, vc-0, cc-0;

System.out.println("Enter a sentence: ");

sen sc.nextLine();

sen sen.toUpperCase();

sen sen+" ";

slen sen.length();

System.out.println("WORD COUNT:-");

for (i = 0; i<slen; i++)
{
ch sen.charAt(1);

if (ch= 'A' || ch== 'E' || ch== 'I' || ch=='0' || ch== 'U')

{

vc++;

} 

else if(ch != 'A' || ch!= 'E' || ch!= 'I' || ch!='0' || ch!='U' || ch!='')

Comment: cc++;

}

if (ch==' ')

{ 
System.out.print(wd+" ");

wd="":
}
else
wd=wd+ch;

}
}
for (int j = 0; j<vc; j++)
{
System.out.print("V");

}

System.out.println();

for (int k = 0; k<cc; k++)

{

System.out.print("C");
}
System.out.println();

for (i = 0; i<slen; i++)

{

ch sen.charAt(i);

if (ch=='.' || ch== '?' || ch=='')

System.out.println("INCORRECT TERMINATING CHARACTER. INVALID INPUT.");
}
}

}

Comment: Please re-edit your question and put your code there.

Comment: That says that it is too long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example.

Maintain a *String* for both *vowels*, and *consonants*; I'm using *a* and *b*.
Divide the text, *s*, with the *[String#split](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))* *method*, and traverse each value.
From here, increment *x* by *1* for vowels, and *y* by *1* for *consonants*.
After the *loop*, print out an occurrence of either *"V"*, or *"C"*, for each *x* and *y*, with the *[String#repeat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int))* method.

```java
String s = "HOW ARE YOU?",
       a = "aeiou", b = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz";
int i, n, x, y;
char c;
for (String w : s.split(" +")) {
    System.out.println(w);
    x = y = 0;
    for (i = 0, n = w.length(); i < n; i++) {
        c = Character.toLowerCase(w.charAt(i));
        if (a.indexOf(c) != -1) x++;
        else if (b.indexOf(c) != -1) y++;
    }
    System.out.println("V".repeat(x));
    System.out.println("C".repeat(y));
    System.out.println();
}
```

Alternately, utilize the *[Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html)* class to traverse each word.

```java
Scanner s = new Scanner("HOW ARE YOU?");
String w, a = "aeiou", b = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz";
int i, n, x, y;
char c;
while (s.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(w = s.next());
    x = y = 0;
    for (i = 0, n = w.length(); i < n; i++) {
        c = Character.toLowerCase(w.charAt(i));
        if (a.indexOf(c) != -1) x++;
        else if (b.indexOf(c) != -1) y++;
    }
    System.out.println("V".repeat(x));
    System.out.println("C".repeat(y));
    System.out.println();
}
```

Output

```
HOW
V
CC

ARE
VV
C

YOU?
VV
C
```